# How do I destroy tanks in Crysis?

Tags: crysis

We just saved this Asian scientist chick and now I 'have to take out the tank'. I have no idea how to do this.

Please help.

Comment: This is a famous gameplay fail in Crysis. It's not clear at all how to destroy the tanks. I shot a couple of missiles then ran out, but didn't bother trying more missiles because they had no visible effect (unlike frag grenades, which at least made the tanks on the back smoke)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need a missile launcher. There should be a launcher in some room on the 1st floor, and I also think there's one on the roof. I'm pretty sure there are additional launchers lying around, maybe in other buildings.

Be aware a tank takes 3 missile hits to kill. Just shoot and run away until it's down - don't remain stationary while shooting all 3. The tanks should appear in your minimap.

Comment: oh thats why they take so long to kill? I'm actually in the part where we clear a station and this place is swarming with tanks. And I was going kinda frustrated to see that I'm firing missile after missile and nothing seems to happen to them.

Comment: You can destroy a tank as well with one of the installed machine guns from the top of the building.

Answer (score 0):

You can destoy a tank with a single missile by shooting the turret.

Comment: really? I could never get to hit it.

Answer (score -1):

The front of the tanks are it's strongest part. Whenever you can, try to shoot at the rear/behind the tank